# Remove "Press one more time to exit" toast message in React Native when pressing the back button

Tags: android, react-native

How do I remove the toast message **"Press one more time to exit."** in **React Native** when pressing the back button on an Android phone?

Comment: Check this link [React Native Device Back Button handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031085/react-native-device-back-button-handling).